# Skorokhod representation in the metric space case

Tags: probability-theory

Here is a possible proof: http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/~schmu/stat671/skorohod.pdf

I have not been able to verify it because one of the last steps is to show that the $X_n$ he constructs have the distributions $\mu_n$.  Can someone help me with this?  I got the pi-lambda application down pat.  So we just need to show agreement of these two measures on his set $\mathcal{C}$.  Towards this, it seems like it would be important to show that the pushforwards via the $X_n$ assign $0$ mass to the boundary of the members of C.

Is this proof correct?

I also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem) that actually completeness is not necessary.  That's a little hard for me to believe.  If we at least assumed that there exists a complete metric space extension of $S$ such that $S$ is borel in this extension, then of course we are fine by just using this complete metric extension.  I also don't really see why $\mu$ is the only measure that needs to be separably supported.

Comment: Can someone tell me what's wrong with the wikipedia link above and how to make links look nicer in general?  Someone comes around and edits it every time.

Comment: Should be fine now. Use \[link-description](http://link.com) ...